# Getting specific node from children props React

Tags: reactjs

I'm quite new to React. Is there a way to get a specific node from an array of children props. So I have a component that accepts children. `<CustomComponent> {children} </CustomComponent`. Children property is an array of elements with a lot of child nodes.

```
<div> <h1> Title </h1> <p> Paragraph </p> <span> Text </span> <button> Text </button> </div>
```

Is there a way for CustomComponent to get only the `<h1>` tag using `React.Children`?

Comment: Could you please expand on your reason why you need to do so?

Comment: I want the CustomComponent to display only h1 tags

Comment: Okay, and why can't you only pass the `h1` element to your custom component?

Comment: This is something I can't control

Comment: Sorry for more questions... I just want to be sure I understand the breadth of your problem so I can try recommend a practical solution. Why can't u control the inputs?

Comment: It's okay. It's a component within a component so I just got the children props from it's parent component that's why I can't control it.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can attach refs to child elements you want to fetch. So that you can do that :

```
this.props.children.refs['yourRefKey']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this is doable by using the `refs` attribute and then accessing it later.

`<input type="text" ref="myinput">`

then

`this.refs.yourref`